# descargar archivo al hacer click en un recycler view

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

A ver si podeis ayudarme por que no se que hacer

mi intencion es que en el recyclerview al hacer click me descargue un archivo en funcion del enlace proporcionado por el sql

ya he probado todos los metodos que se y que he buscado pero no hay manera

espero podais ayudarme

un saludo

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class RVAdaptermanuales extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdaptermanuales.DatosmanualesViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<manuales> listamanuales;

    class DatosmanualesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout cuerpo;
        TextView banco, descripcion, enlace;

        DatosmanualesViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            cuerpo = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.cuerpo);
            banco = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.banco);
            descripcion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
            enlace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.enlace);
        }
    }

    RVAdaptermanuales(ArrayList<manuales> listamanuales) {this.listamanuales = listamanuales;}

    @Override
    public DatosmanualesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vistadelrvmanuales,parent,false);
        return new DatosmanualesViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DatosmanualesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.banco.setText(listamanuales.get(position).getManuales());
        holder.descripcion.setText(listamanuales.get(position).getDescripcion());
        holder.enlace.setText(listamanuales.get(position).getEnlace());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listamanuales.size();
    }
}
```

ahora el activity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ManualesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView rvmanuales;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_manuales);
        rvmanuales = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvmanuales);
        rvmanuales.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rvmanuales.setLayoutManager(llm);
        String consulta = "***************************";
        EnviarRecibirDatos(consulta);
    }



    public void EnviarRecibirDatos(String URL) {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                response = response.replace("][", ",");
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                        Log.i("sizejson", "" + ja.length());
                        CargarListView(ja);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    public void CargarListView(JSONArray ja) {

        ArrayList<manuales> listamanuales = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i += 5) {

            try {
                manuales manuales = new manuales(ja.getString(i + 2),"**********************" + ja.getString(i + 4),ja.getString(i + 3) );
                listamanuales.add(manuales);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        RVAdaptermanuales adaptadorRV = new RVAdaptermanuales(listamanuales);
        rvmanuales.setAdapter(adaptadorRV);


    }
}
```

aunque no tiene nada que ver pero bueno...

```
class manuales {


    private String manuales, descripcion, enlace;


    manuales(String manuales, String descripcion, String enlace) {
        this.manuales = manuales;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.enlace = enlace;

    }

    String getManuales() {
        return manuales;
    }
    String getDescripcion(){return descripcion;}
    String getEnlace(){return enlace;}
    }
```

Comment: Y cual es el error que te muestra al tratar de descargarlo? cual es el problema especifico?

Comment: Se que tal cual esta solamente muestra los datos pero al hacerle el onclicklistener no hace nada, nisiquiera he conseguido que todas las lineas descarguen un mismo archivo.

Comment: Para empezar te recomiendo de añadir un `Log.d` o un `Toast` en tu `Response.ErrorListener` y en  `onResponse`. Luego revisas que te sale mal.

Answer (score 0):

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

class RVAdaptermanuales extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
private final Context context;
private List<manuales> listamanuales;

static class DatosmanualesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context context;
    TextView banco, descripcion, enlace;
    DatosmanualesViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        banco = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.banco);
        descripcion = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        enlace = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.enlace);
        context = itemView.getContext();
    }
}

RVAdaptermanuales(List<manuales> listamanuales) {
    this.listamanuales = listamanuales;
    context = null;
}

@Override
public DatosmanualesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vistadelrvmanuales,parent,false);

    return new DatosmanualesViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DatosmanualesViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.banco.setText(listamanuales.get(position).getBanco());
    holder.descripcion.setText(listamanuales.get(position).getDescripcion());
    holder.enlace.setText(listamanuales.get(position).getEnlace());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Solo falta enlazar" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listamanuales.size();
}
```

}

es lo que me ha dado tiempo antes de irme a currar

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

vale ya esta me muestra un toast sin problema.

Ahora la consulta es solamente para que abra un enlace de descarga en funcion del enlace que proporciona el sql. Los datos del recycler ya los saca de una base de datos sql pero no funciona. esto es lo que tengo pero aqui ya estoy perdido completamente

```
                        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = (Uri.parse("http://ares.astursistemas.es/ficheros/manuales/" ));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

si despues del enlace le agrego +descripcion.getText().toString() no valida el codigo y asi es como lo tengo hecho en el resto de la app

un saludo